# saving components issue with keywords Sites 9.1

Tags: keyword, sites-9.1

We did upgrade for one of the customer from SDL 8.5 to Sites 9.1 and we are having issues saving the component with keywords.

Keyword with title 'Country Region' does not exist in Category 'Country'
Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Category.GetKeywordDataByTitle(String title) at
Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Category.GetKeywordByTitle(String title) at
Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Fields.ItemField.ReadFromElement(XmlNodeList fieldNodes) at
XmlElement contentContainer, Nullable`1 synchronizeFlags, LoadFlags loadFlags) at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to this [Link](https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000012744)

if you need more information please contact support.

Hope this helps !

Please apply the following hotfix to resolve the issue

Issue resolved with hotfixes:

- For Tridion Sites 9.0, apply CM_9.0.0.18792 and CME_9.0.0.19300.
- For Tridion Sites 9.1, apply CM_9.1.0.18792 and CME_9.1.0.19300.

Comment: Hey Anand, you may want to include (part) of the solution in your answers, as the page you link to could change or be removed in the future, and other people with the same question will not be able to find the solution.